# How can i execute tcl command [using tclsh prompt] remotely using python 2.7 module?

Tags: python-2.7, tcl, paramiko, tclsh

Here is my set up.
Windows PC1 where Python 2.7 code is running ----> Windows PC2 where tcl is installed.

Windows PC1 and Windows PC2 are connected through LAN and able to access each other.

Now i want to open CMD line (As administrator) of PC2 from PC1 using python and execute windows command.
Yes this can be achieved through paramiko.

Now i want to run "tclsh" command in PC2 command prompt. After this the command line goes inside tcl prompt [%].Here i can execute tcl command like puts "Welcome". So if i try to execute "tclsh" command through paramiko its is in waiting state as the prompt has been changed from windows prompt to %.

My intention is to run tcl command in tclsh prompt [PC2 cmd line] through python [PC1].

Example: From PC1 i want to execute "puts "Hello" to PC2 tcl prompt through python2.7.

**Please suggest me some idea what can be used [python module or any other approach] to access tclsh prompt through python 2.7.**

Through paramiko normal windows commands are working as expected but tclsh enter into % prompt so paramiko is not working in this scenario.

I want to get access to tcl prompt through python 2.7 remotely.

I want to execute tcl command inside tclsh prompt in remote system through python.Here is the small program i have tried .

```
host = '192.168.1.4'
user = 'lenovo'
passw = 'XXX'

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=passw)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('tclsh')
print (str('.'.join(stdout.readlines())))
print (str('.'.join(stdin.readlines())))
print (str('.'.join(stderr.readlines())))
```

But i do not see any output as tclsh goes into new % prompt. How do i solve this? After i have access to tclsh % prompt i want to execute "**puts "Welcome"**"
.Instead of tclsh if give "hostname" windows command i get reply.

Comment: *"I have tried to use paramiko to do this but it did not work"* - This does not work for us as a description of **what** you did and **how** it failed - We need [mcve] -- Can you do what you want using an SSH terminal client? Until you can do, what you need, using an SSH client, there's no point trying to implement the same using Paramiko -- Until then, you do not have a programming question.

Comment: May be it's not a programming question. It's a kind of scenario i am not able to implement.I want =>through python 2.7 access tclsh prompt and execute tcl command pragmatically.

Comment: You didn't answer my question ---  Can you do what you want using an SSH terminal client?

Comment: Sorry if i was not clear. I have added more details in my question. Please check,

Answer (score 0):

I got the solutions to access tclsh prompt for a remote windows pc using pramiko in python 2.7.

Step1: Use invoke shell method for tclsh command for the first time and store the return of invoke_shell to a globa variable.Suppose the return is x.

Step2: Now for any other command for tclsh prompt [like cmd = puts "stack"] use like x.send(cmd+"\n")

Step3: Now we can get output buffer like x.recv(9999)

Note [For windows only]: x.recv(9999) returns actual output with many escape sequences. We need to clean that to get the actual data.